# Compiler running on a network

Tags: compiler-construction, networking

i am asking a quite descriptve question , so if possible suggest me some useful links or related information on how i can proceed to develop a network compiler (compiler that runs on the internet or LAN )

Answer (score 1):

Is this the type of thing you are looking for: http://distcc.samba.org/.

I can't find it, but I seem to reminder Borland doing something like this too...

Answer (score 0):

you might be interested in something like Open MPI

```
  www.open-mpi.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

AT&T [`nmake` and `coshell`](http://www.research.att.com/~gsf/) make it easy to distributed compilation jobs over a network.  They run on Unix and also on windows over AT&T U/Win.

It's not very clear from the question, but I hope that's what you wanted.  It's hard to imagine what benefit there is for the compiler to be aware that it's running on the network.  You want the build system (e.g., `nmake`) to be aware of that.  Separation of concerns...